# Rails nested models with comments as commentable (polymorphic association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, ruby-on-rails-5

I have question and answer models with the comment to both as commentable. Comments on the question work fine but on the answer I am getting: "undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass." Following is the code:

**controller/comment_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController      
  before_action :authenticate_user!    
  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params        
    @comment.user = current_user        
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Thanks for your comment."    
  end      
  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

**controller/questions/comment_controller.rb**

```
class Questions::CommentsController < CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable      
  private      
    def set_commentable
      @commentable = Question.find_by_permalink(params[:question_id])
    end      
end
```

**controller/questions/answers/comment_controller.rb**

```
class Answers::CommentsController < CommentsController      
  before_action :set_commentable      
  private      
    def set_commentable
      @question = Question.find_by_permalink(params[:question_id])
      @commentable = @question.answers.find(params[:answer_id])       
    end      
end
```

**Models**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers,    dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments,   as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Answer < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :comments,   as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy 
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :questions do
    resources :comments, module: :questions 
      resources :answers, :only => [:create, :destroy, :update] do
        resources :comments, module: :answers
    end end
```

**Question: show.html.erb:**

```
<h1><%= link_to @question.title, question_path(@question)%></h1>
<p><%= @question.description %></p>
<%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question } %>
<%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @question } %>

<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
 <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @answer } %>
 <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: @answer } %>
<% end %>
```

**_comments.html.erb**

```
    <div class="content">
   <h2 class="title"><%= pluralize(commentable.comments.count, 'Comment', plural: 'Comments') %></h2>           
        <% commentable.comments.each do |comment| %>             
            <small><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></small> 
            <p><%= comment.content %></p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class:'textarea', placeholder:'Add a comment' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Comment', class:'button is-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**
Strange thing happend. I reset the database and altest I can add comment to the answer now, not sure how it got fixed. 
However I am getting a new error which make more sense: undefined method `answer_comments_path' for #<#:0x007f89e04905b8>. I have put <%= answer.inspect %> just before the comment input form to the answer and I am getting as expected answer model data.

So when I do the rake routes i dont see answer_comments_path. 
The route is question_answer_comments_path. How can I pass this path to the answer/comments form.

Comment: `for nil:NilClass.` this is the relevant part... it means you don't actually have anything stored in your variable... In your answers controller, I want you to test what you actually get in each of the `@`-variables by doing this: `puts "question is: #{@question.inspect} and commentable is: #{@commentable.inspect}"` - then run the action and look into your sever logs (in the terminal window or in log/development.log) and see what gets printed out. let us know...

Comment: see updates to the question.

Comment: The routing issue is because you *only* have the answers path nested under your questions routes... if you want answers to have their own path, then you need it not to be nested inside the question-path (or you need to declare it both inside the question path and by itself).  At this point I *strongly* recommend you read the rails guide on routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (and all of them - it's the best way to level up in rails)